# PHP PDO error using SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if ($_GET['id']) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $db = new SQLite3('database.db');

    $sth = $db->query('SELECT * FROM channels WHERE id = :id');
    $sth->bindValue(':id', $id);

    while ($row = $sth->fetchArray()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::bindValue() in /var/www/index.html on line 12

I do not understand what `Call to undefined method` means since I am following the examples on PHP's own website.

Comment: You need to call `$db->prepare()`, not `$db->query()`. `query` returns a result set; `prepare` returns a statement.

Answer (score 3):

`prepare()`

Where is that? If you were following the manual correctly you would be preparing a statement and that statement would provide `bindValue()` method :)

By executing a query directly on the database handle you don't get the features that statements provide. You have to create an `SQLite3Stmt` object for it.

Like this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM channels WHERE id=:id');
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php)**